# MATLAB CUDA Kernel Object- Error using gather?

Tags: c++, matlab, cuda, output-parameter, matlab-gpu

I have the following [CUDAKernel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel.gpu.cudakernel.html) object:

[image: workspace]

Which I invoke using:

```
kernel1 = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('kcc2.ptx', 'kcc2.cu');
kernel1.ThreadBlockSize = 256;
kernel1.GridSize = 4;

gpuTM = gpuArray(single(TM));
gpuLTM = gpuArray(single(LTM));
gpuLTMP = gpuArray(int32(LTMP));

rng('shuffle');
randz = abs(randi(2^53 -1, [1, r_max]));
GPUrands = gpuArray(double(randz));

[x,y] = gather(feval(kernel1, gpuLTM, gpuLTMP, F_M, Force, GPUrands, ...
    (r_max), single(Lamda), single(Fixed_dt), single(r), single(q), ...
    single(gama_B), single(gama_M), single(mu_B), single(mu_M), ...
    single(KB_p_ref), single(KB_m_ref), single(f_ref), single(g_ref), ...
    single(Kca_p_ref), single(Kca_m_ref)));
```

As you see above, I have 2 left hand arguments yet I get the error in MATLAB:

> Error using gpuArray/gather:
>   Too many output arguments.

I don't get it. All my parameters line up in the CUDA kernel and in MATLAB. Just so you can see, the kernel function has the following C++ prototype:

```
__global__ void myKern(const float *transMatrix, const int *pointerMatrix, 
    float *masterForces, float *Force, const double *rands, const int r_max, 
    const float lamda, const float dt, const float r, const float q, 
    const float gama_B, const float gama_M, const float mu_B, const float mu_M, 
    const float KB_p_ref, const float KB_m_ref, const float f_ref, 
    const float g_ref, const float Kca_p_ref, const float Kca_m_ref)
```

It should only return `masterForces` and `Force` (`[x,y]` in MATLAB) since they are the only non-constant pointers.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply `gather` directly on multiple output variables, you have to do that in separate lines (this is basic MATLAB syntax):

```
[x,y] = feval(kernel1, ...);
x = gather(x);
y = gather(y);
```

The output of evaluating the CUDA kernel is two variables of type `gpuArray` (data stored on the GPU). You can then transfer the data to CPU memory using `gather` applied on each variable.